# is there any POSIX way through fstat() to check whether a file is a symbolic link or not?

Tags: linux, posix, symlink

Is there any POSIX way through `fstat(2)` to check whether a file is a symbolic link or not?

There is flag `O_NOFOLLOW` in `open(2)` which can check it, however, it's not POSIX.

There is `S_ISLNK` in `fstat(2)`, which is said in `man fstat`:

```
   The S_ISLNK() and S_ISSOCK() macros are not in POSIX.1-1996,
   but both are present in POSIX.1-2001; the former is from SVID
   4, the latter from SUSv2.
```

and the compile will fail on my machine.

Also, there is another `S_IFLNK` in `lstat(2)`, however, it won't work with `fstat(2)` (which will follow the link to the file referred to).

Comment: How about using both `fstat` and `lstat` and compare inodes?

Comment: A symlink points to a real file whch is what you ultimately open.  From the fd it makes no sense to find out what path you used to open it (which may no longer even exist)

Comment: @KerrekSB: The `lstat` function will return the inode for the symlink, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 5):

No.

It's not true that `fstat` follows symlinks.  Instead, `open` follows symlinks.  Once you get to `fstat`, it is too late and the information is gone.

**Tell us** why you need to know, and we can help with that problem.  (Open another question.)

**How files work:**

Here is some pseudo-C / shell code:

```
system("echo 'Hello, World!' >A.txt");
system("ln A.txt B.txt");
system("ln -s A.txt C.txt");

fdes = open("C.txt");
unlink("A.txt");
unlink("C.txt");
data = read(fdes);
write(stdout, data);
```

The result: your program prints `"Hello, world!"`.  The state of the world looks like this:

```
+--Application--+    +--Kernel--+    +-------Disk-------+
|               |    |          |    |                  |
|  fdes --------------> file ---------> inode #973 <-------+
|               |    |          |    |  "Hello World!"  |  |
+---------------+    +----------+    |                  |  |
                                     |  directory ---------+
                                     |  "B.txt"         |
                                     |                  |
                                     +------------------+
```

As far as the kernel is concerned, the file open is "inode #973".  The data structure in kernel memory has some additional information such as the current position, but it does NOT know the path.  The kernel is not expected to know that information.

If you asked the kernel what the path is, it *could* say "you have B.txt" open.  But you never opened "B.txt", you opened "C.txt" which was a symlink to "A.txt", and both "A.txt" and "C.txt" have been deleted (they were just names to begin with).

**Simple analogy:**

You get a phone call from an old friend.  He asks, "Did I look up your number in the phone directory, did I memorize it, or did I have to ask someone for your number?"

You have no way of knowing the answer.  All you know is who is on the other end of the line.  Just like an open file doesn't store information about what it was named (hard link or symbolic link), it just has information about permissions and data.

**The solution:** Just use `lstat` (yes, there is a race condition).  If you didn't open the file yourself (e.g., you get it from a parent process or you get it over a socket), then it's more or less impossible to know if it was opened through a symbolic link.

Comment: besides O_NOFOLLOW, is there other way to check the file with open()?

Comment: To add to the fun, it could be that it was opened via a symlink that no longer exists, or indeed the symlink may point to a different file with the same name (ie, the first file was unlinked)!

Comment: it's unsafe to use lstat(). for example, if we will write something to a file A, the file is checked OK by using lstat(), however, before opening the file, the symbolic link is replaced by another file B which is not supposed to be written by the user. then the check in lstat() doesn't take effect. however, if using open() and fstat(), these wouldn't happen, since the file descriptor is operated.

Comment: @wenlujon: I mentioned in an earlier edit that `lstat` had a race condition, I'll add it back.  But `open` / `fstat` doesn't work because you can't open a symlink, only the file it points to.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  What is the end goal?  Maybe we could help with that?

Comment: what I want is 1) check if the file is a symbolic link, if yes, exit. 2) open the file and read content of it. 3) the file in 1) and 2) must be the same file. 4) all these must be done under POSIX way.

Comment: @wenlujon: Yes, but what is the goal?  If I don't understand why you need to know if it is a symbolic link, I can't help.

Comment: for security. for example, there is a file A defines what kind of operations a user USER can do as root. and the file A　is located in a dir DIR_A which USER has write permission, but USER doesn't have write permission on file A. the attacker can delete file A, and create a symbolic link file A refers to another file B which contains dangerous operations. to avoid such attack, we can check the file A whether it's a symbolic link and whether it has write permission.

Comment: @wenlujon: Symbolic links do not have permissions.  You should check permissions on the file with `fstat`.

Comment: what I mean is that if it's a symbolic link, the check failed immediately, the write permission is checked only if it's not a symbolic link.

Comment: However, if the user has write permission to DIR_A then the user can put any file there, *including* files owned by root (hard links).  It is insecure whether or not the user can create symbolic links.